# How to find multiple files in linux system

Tags: linux, command-line, find-in-files

I have massive of files in my system and every file has one corresponded file name. For example,

`test.pdf` has a `test-project.zip`
`test2.pdf` has a `test2-project.zip`

`test.pdf` and `test2.pdf` are the original files and `test-project.zip` and `test2-project.zip` are generated by my script.

I need to find out if all of my original files have the `'filename'-project.zip` corresponded to the original file.

I can use

```
find /project/ -name "*.pdf" | wc -l
find /project/ -name "*-project.zip" | wc -l
```

to find out if the numbers match but I need to know which file has no corresponded file.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it a single folder `/project/`, or are subdirectories involved?

Comment: subdirectories included..

Comment: is `test.pdf` and `test-project.zip` (and so on) always in the same directory?

Comment: yes they are all in the same dir

Answer (score 5):

Quicky script, adapt as you see fit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find /project/ -name '*.pdf' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' i; do
  if [ ! -e "${i/%.pdf/-project.zip}" ]; then
    echo "${i/%.pdf/-project.zip} doesn't exist!"
  fi
done

exit 0
```

`-d $'\0'` sets the delimiter for `read` to nullbyte, while `-print0` is the equivalent for `find`, so this should be bulletproof against files with spaces and newlines in their names (obviously irrelevant in this case, but useful to know in general). `${i/%.pdf/-project.zip}` replaces the `.pdf` at the end of the variable `$i` with `-project.zip`. Other than that, this is all standard shell scripting stuff.

If you wanted to shorten it even more, you could also use

```
[ -e "${i/%.pdf/-project.zip}" ] || echo "${i/%.pdf/-project.zip} doesn't exist!"
```

...instead of the `if` statement. I think that `if` is easier to work with if you're using more than a single, short line (you can get around this by using a function, but at that point you aren't getting any psace saving vs. using the `if`).

Assuming you have bash 4+ (you probably do; you can check with `bash --version`), you can use the globstar option instead of `find`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar
for f in /project/**/*.pdf; do
  if [ ! -e "${f/%.pdf/-project.zip}" ]; then
    echo "${f/%.pdf/-project.zip} doesn't exist!"
  fi
done

exit 0
```

This has the advantage of being pure bash, so it should be faster (only noticeably so with at least hundreds of files, though).

Comment: You guard against newlines, but the `[ ... ]` test would still break if $i had spaces.

Comment: @grawity - I can't believe I forgot to quote the variable, fixed.

Comment: +1 for '-d '\0'... but do you need /bin/env bash? /bin/bash is a POSIX necessity. Do you really worry about which bash you hit?

Comment: @RichHomolka AFAIK there's no actual downside to using `/usr/bin/env`, and while it may not be necessary in this case, I look at it as a good habit to form for working with other laguages.

Comment: @RichHomolka: **`/bin/sh`** is a POSIX necessity. `bash`, on the other hand, is a third-party program, and it's frequently in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or even `/usr/pkg/bin`.

Comment: @grawity maybe I'm just thinking SVR4, which required it. Thanks

Comment: @RichHomolka: bash didn't exist when SVR4 was released, afaik

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you could do it. One is a godawful Bash one-liner which spawns at least one, possibly two, processes for each file it matches:

```
[me@box] $ for file in `find -name '*.pdf' -exec perl -le'$f=shift(); $f =~ s@\.pdf$@@; print $f' {} \;`; do (TESTFILE="$file-project.zip"; if [ ! -f $TESTFILE ]; then echo "missing $TESTFILE"; fi); done
```

Since that's enough to make anyone's eyes bleed, here's a Perl script which does the same job, much more sanely than any Bash script ever could:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $path = shift() || die "$0 requires a path argument\n";
my @files = `find "$path" -name '*.pdf'`;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  chomp $file;
  my $zip = $file;
  $zip =~ s@\.pdf$@-project.zip@;
  next if -f $zip;
  print "missing $zip\n";
};
```

Copy that into, e.g., 'find-missing.pl', then invoke `find-missing.pl /project/`.

Comment: `for file in \`find …` is a common anti-pattern and should be avoided. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs